# Rewrite - 2 files with same parameters and located in same folder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know that was a frequent question here in SO, but I can't rewrite some dynamics URL.

Hope someone can help me.

I've 2 files located in the same folder, that receive same number of parameters:

> .com/serie.php?id=**__123__**&nombre=**__string__**
>
> .com/episodio.php?idSerie=**__123__**&query=**__1x1__**

My desired pretty url are this:

> *for serie.php:* .com/**__123__**/***string***
>
> *for episodio.php:* .com/**__123__**/**string**/**1x1**-some-other-strings-not-relevants-here

I was able to make the first rewrite, like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite Serie.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /serie.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /serie.php?id=$1&nombre=$2 [L]
```

Work fine, but the problem comes in the second rewrite.

The **bold** characters are "relevants" and I use this, to make some work.

I tried something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-([^/]*)$ /episodio.php?idSerie=$1&query=$2 [L]
```

But I get 404 not found.

How can make this second rewrite?

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ serie.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ serie.php?id=$1&nombre=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/[^/]+/([^-]+)-[^/]*/?$ serie.php?id=$1&query=$2 [L,QSA]
```